# How to find UIKeyboard Notifiactions outside of our app(app running in background)...........?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard

I want to know if user using keyboard outside,when my app running in background.?

I have to know whether user sending a text message using default Messaging app in iPhone.

I  tried in this way:

> By using Keyboard we can send Text Messages(80%),when ever user presses any key in keyboard outside of our app how we can know?.

I searched a lot,i found with in the app by using UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, but when app running in background?

Please Share Answer if any....!
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: why on the Earth are you interested in when any other application uses the keyboard? that is their private thing, as your app's personal issue when you use the keyboard, no one has to access the typed information.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, Is there any way to find whether user texting while driving through Default Message App in iPhone,please help to find is there any way for this....?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because when your app is running in background mode it does not execute any code from you application.

Only some limited tasks/background modes are supported.

**Please check following link for more information:** https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3.

Comment: This documentation refers to iOS 7, I believe, whereas the OP's query regards the unreleased iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, Is there any way to find whether user texting while driving through Default Message App in iPhone,please help to find is there any way for this....?

Answer (score 0):

App can only listen the Keyboard notification only when the app is in running state and notification is with in the app only in ios.

However there are the notifications in OS X, an application can listen the keyboard notification outside the app.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, Is there any way to find whether user texting while driving through Default Message App in iPhone,please help to find is there any way for this....?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2):

> While an extension is running, it communicates directly only with the
>   host app. There is no direct communication between a running extension
>   and its containing app; typically, the containing app isn’t even
>   running while its extension is running. In addition, the containing
>   app and the host app don’t communicate at all.

[image: Simplified app communication diagram]

You can request network access for your keyboard, but my guess is that most people would refrain from downloading any keyboard that has the capacity to log their keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply, Is there any way to find whether user texting while driving through Default Message App in iPhone,please help to find is there any way for this....?

Comment: No. Your custom keyboard cannot interact with the host application, so you can't know what application the user is currently interacting with. This may be possible for jailbroken iPhones, but you cannot currently do this using a custom keyboard distributed through the App Store.

Comment: Is there any way to find whether user ,texting or not by using Default Message app?

Comment: No. You cannot hook into the default messaging app.

Comment: Is there any other way to find that texting?

Comment: I'm sorry Krishna Stv. You cannot achieve this on a standard iOS installation.